# Base 64 convertion error angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, base64

I am trying to decode a base64 image from JSON data and trying to bind it over to the DOM, but the image is not being displayed.

Please check the following code:

```js
.then(function mySuccess(response) {

        $rootScope.vehiclenumber = response.data.vehicleNumber;
        $rootScope.emailDriver = response.data.email;
        imgUrl: "data:image/png;base64," + response.data.image;
        $rootScope.userNamedriver = response.data.Name;
        $rootScope.namedriver = response.data.userName;
        console.log($rootScope.imgUrl);

        $state.go('app.user');

      }
```

```html
<div>

<img data-ng-src="image/png;base64,{{imgURL}}" />


</div>
```

When I consoled imgURL, it is undefined.

Comment: Right now, `imgURL` is a label, and `"data:image/png;base64," + response.data.image` is an orphaned expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

I have put imgUrl on rootScope too.
Untested though, and not sure if using rootScope is the best place to store your data, though.

Also note that you used imgURL instead of imgUrl in your template.

```
.then(function mySuccess(response) {
    $rootScope.vehiclenumber = response.data.vehicleNumber;
    $rootScope.emailDriver = response.data.email;
    $rootScope.imgUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + response.data.image;
    $rootScope.userNamedriver = response.data.Name;
    $rootScope.namedriver = response.data.userName;
    console.log($rootScope.imgUrl);

    $state.go('app.user');

  }


<div>
    <img data-ng-src="{{imgUrl}}" />   
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! but still imgUrl is undefined

Comment: Hei, I have fixed it, thanks. There is a slight change in your code too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code for the same.
I have done similar task in Angular 5, so please follow below steps:-

1)  Create a function as below
    getFileEncode(fileType: string) {

```
    var encodevalue: string;
    switch (fileType.toUpperCase()) {

        case "PNG": encodevalue = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'; break;
        case "JPG": encodevalue = 'data:image/png;base64,'; break;
        case "GIF": encodevalue = 'data:image/gif;base64,'; break;

    }
    return encodevalue;
}

2)  Var fileData = this.getFileEncode("PNG") + response.data.image;
//response.data.image should contain a byte array.

3)  Now bind to SRC of img tag as follows
$('#preview').attr('src', fileData).fadeIn('slow');
```

4)  You are receiving data in json from webserver, so you should take care of it for getting the bytearray from json, might be you need some conversion.